# "Connecting to Integration Service failed..." SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Please see below. We have SSIS services installed and running, but it appears we cannot connect to them.

What is the path to get them set up and working?

```
TITLE: SSIS Execution Properties
------------------------------

Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer "886319-DB1C" failed with the following error: "The specified service does not exist as an installed service.".

This error can occur when you try to connect to a SQL Server 2005 Integration Services service from the current version of the SQL Server tools. Instead, add folders to the service configuration file to let the local Integration Services service manage packages on the SQL Server 2005 instance.


For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506689

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer "886319-DB1C" failed with the following error: "The specified service does not exist as an installed service.".

This error can occur when you try to connect to a SQL Server 2005 Integration Services service from the current version of the SQL Server tools. Instead, add folders to the service configuration file to let the local Integration Services service manage packages on the SQL Server 2005 instance.


------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

I was using SSMS 17.1 against SQL Server 2016.

SSMS 17 works great w SQL Server 2016.... except it cannot connect to SQL 2016 SSIS. To connect to SQL 2016 SSIS, you must use SSMS 16.x

Installed SSMS 2016, (v16.x), and it connects fine to Integration Services.

Comment: Pretty true for all SSIS versions... It's always recommended to use the respective SSMS version to connect to them. Main reason I have 4 versions of SSMS on my machine!

Comment: @GarethLyons Yup. I am new to SSIS, so had not hit this before. I have always been a "one version of ssms" guy (managing at least 3 vers of sql server), but am now a multi-ssms guy..... ack!